# Why won't my javascript widget allow me to resize?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, resize

I am using a third-party widget on my website. The widget is coded in Javascript and does not appear to have any indication of size. However, I need to make the widget smaller. Original code provided from the third-party:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.worldbookonline.com/widgets/WorldBook_Widget_1_0.js" 
charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">worldbook_widget("ST","N8106")</script>
```

So, I've been reading that if I put in a div element, I can add a size style, so I tried the following. The widget still works but the size did not change at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<div style="height:200px; widget:100px; border: 0px solid black;">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.worldbookonline.com/widgets/WorldBook_Widget_1_0.js" 
charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">worldbook_widget("ST","N8106")</script>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Just FYI, Java isn't JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the src of your widget in the script tag all together

`<script src="here the font of your widget">worldbook_widget("ST","N8106")</script>`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding. I was using info from a help article on Adobe. It said to do what I want, to add the html and div style and then close the whole code with div and html. Where are you telling me the style goes?

Comment: HTML code needs an basic structure for put the links the elements that you want to show, here is what I'm trying to say: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp but I was checkin your code in javascript and I found this page, tell me if I'ts correct? https://www.askri.org/resources/world-book/ Because It's same in what you put in your asking

Comment: While the link provided does offer a widget to the same database, the coding is different. I am unsure why. The code I received from the company has uses ("ST","N8106) while the one you provided uses ("ST","00M7105"). I am unsure what the difference is. It's ok. I clearly have a lot of learning to do. Thank you for trying to help. I appreciate it.